# ChangeNotifier inaccessible in grandchildren widget of where it was provided

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to use flutter provider in order to carry my state down a widget sub-tree/route, and while it works for the direct child of the widget that provided the change notifier class, it does not for the next one in line.
As far as I understand, the change notifier class should be passed down. To be more specific, I am trying to access it through context.read() in a function being called in its initState function.
Am I doing something wrong?

The code below illustrates my code.
Where it class notifier is provided:

```
onTap: () {
  // Select body area
  context.read<Patient>().selectBodyArea(areas[index]);

  // Open complaint list
  FlowRepresentation flow = context.read<Patient>().getFlow();
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: flow,
              child: const ChiefComplaintList()
          )
      )
  );
}
```

Navigation to the problem widget in ChiefComplaintList:

```
onTap: () {
  // Select complaint
  context.read<FlowRepresentation>().selectComplaint(ccs[index]);

  // Show factors
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AttenuationFactors())
  );
}
```

Where I'm having trouble accessing the change notifier class:

```
void getData() async {

  _nrFactors = await context.read<FlowRepresentation>().getAttenuationFactors();
  setState(() {}); // rebuild widget with data
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  print("Initiated Attenuation Factors Lists State");
  getData();
}
```